# Cannot view code coverage on angular-cli new project

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to get code coverage working with @angular/cli but so far i'm not having much luck.

I started a new project using angular CLI. Basically all i did was `ng new test-coverage` and once everything was installed in my new project folder, I did a `ng test --code-coverage`. The tests were run successfully but nothing resembling code coverage was displayed in the browser.

Am I missing some dependencies or something else? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
R. Richards and Rachid Oussanaa were right, the file does get generated and I can access it by opening the index.html.

Now i'm wondering, is there a way I could integrate that into a node command so that the file opens right after the tests are run?

Comment: Did anything get output in the coverage directory? There should be an index.html file that you can view.

Comment: angular-cli will generate an coverage directory in your project directory

Comment: That was it! Thank you guys, i don't know how i missed that...
Is there a way i could integrate that into the `ng test` command? (so it's displayed when the tests are run, or do I have to run it manually everytime?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what you can do:

install [`opn-cli`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn-cli) which is a cli for the popular  [`opn`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn) package which is a cross-platform tool used to open files in their default apps.

`npm install -D opn-cli`   `-D` to install as dev dependency.

in `package.json` add a script under `scripts` as follows

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test-coverage": "ng test --code-coverage --single-run && opn ./coverage/index.html"
}
```

now run `npm run test-coverage`
this will run the script we defined. here is an explanation of that script:

- `ng test --code-coverage --single-run` will run tests, with coverage, only ONCE, hence `--single-run`
- `&&` basically executes the second command if the first succeeds
- `opn ./coverage/index.html` will open the file regardless of platform.

Comment: thank you, worked great. I just used htt-server instead of opn

Comment: I really don't recommend running an http-server for this, but if you insist and it works, go for it :)

Comment: hehe, thanks for the recommandation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server seemed lightweight enough but   if it turns out to be too big of a hassle, i'll switch to opn.

Comment: either or works. it's just my feeling that `http-server` might give you trouble in future. `http-server` also has far more dependencies than `opn` and I assume is far larger in disk-size.